# Tools for Debugging ThreadPool Issues in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I have never spent much time debugging multithreaded .NET apps (or others), and have quite a simple one to solve very quickly.  Ideally I would imagined and would lurve to be able to intercept thread creation and use by worker objects, so that nothing unexpected happens while I'm on a breakpoint in my thread.  Is that realistic?

What else is there in VS 2010?

Comment: You lost me at "lurve".  No, that's not realistic.

Comment: It doesn't have to be.  It was part of my tone and the realism that I was looking for advice on debugging tools was, I think, still apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could freeze all threads except the thread you're currently working with.  This should stop all work being done on all other thread pool threads and should prevent new work from getting queued unless the thread you're working with also queues work.

See [John Robbins' blog on freezing threads](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/07/17/automatically-freezing-threads-brrrrr.aspx).